# Why do we have to define variables while naming the GraphQL queries?

Tags: syntax, graphql

Simply, why is this correct:

```
query HeroNameAndFriends($episode: Episode)
{
  hero(episode: $episode)
   {
    name
    friends 
     {
      name
     }
   }
}
```

and this is incorrect (variable "$episode" is not defined.)?

```
{
    hero(episode: $episode) 
      {
        name
        friends
        {
          name
        }
      }
}
```

What's the reason behind this specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because GraphQL is *statically typed*, and so the graphql type system can validate that the the right variables passing in. Also variables are scoped on a per operation. That means that any variable used within the context of an operation must be defined at the top level of that operation. So thats the reason why you declare the types of variables you are planning to provide.

In order to carry out these and other [rules](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Validation.Variables), the types of variables you are planning to provide must be declared.